# PHP DateTime - Make from YEAR, WEEK and WEEKDAY

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have the year, week, and weekday stored as integers. Weekdays are 0 based, starting with Monday. The variables are equivalent to YEAR(date), WEEK(date) and WEEKDAY(date, 1) functions in MySQL. For example for today (Thursday 30th Oct 2014) it would be:

```
$year = 2014;
$week = 44;
$weekday = 3; // Thursday
```

Using these variables how do I set the date of a DateTime object?

I tried using:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-z", $year . "-" . ((($week - 1) * 7) + $weekday));
```

And a few other variations, but nothing gave me the expected results.

Any ideas?

Comment: First of all, why are you not storing a date in a datetime column?

Comment: Nothing is stored in MySQL like this, I was just giving the MySQL functions as examples of what the variables I do have (which are actually method parameters) are. See my solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution:

```
$year = 2014;
$week = 44;
$weekday = 3; // Thursday

$day_in_question = new DateTime();
$day_in_question->setTime(0, 0, 0);
$day_in_question->setISODate($year, $week_number, $weekday + 1);
```

Seems to give the expected result

Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me as if you need to use [`\DateTime::setISODate()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.setisodate.php). However, you will need to add 1 to the weekday as Monday is 1.

```
$date = (new \DateTime())->setISODate($year, $week, $weekday + 1);
var_dump($date);
```

http://3v4l.org/EVqHj